# Is there a possibility to save a file pointer in My Sql DataBase?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

**I know two of these ways :**

1. Blob Object

Save the file as an object Blob, But there is a Disadvantage to this Method it is increasing the size of the database.

2. Save Path

This is the most effective way I thought it.

**The problem arises when the program's users want to move the file and then Path changes.
Did you think or know any other way? thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its preferable to use the second method. The issue of moving the file is no big problem as you can update your database to the newly moved path

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to store the file on disk using a GUID or some other id as filename and store this id in the database.

Now you can store additional metadata for this file in your SQL database (like an abstract path or the filename). This metadata can be updated without the need to move or rename the stored file.

Please be aware that storing many files in one directory is not very performant. It is better to use a hierarchical path structure with subdirectories.